# Does Flutter have an equivalent onOpen or onStart triggers function?

Tags: flutter, dart

Objective: every time the app launches, execute a one-time function (just for learning purposes).

Some applications have triggers to run one-time functions. Google App Script uses 'onOpen'. Microsoft Power Apps uses 'onStart'. Excel uses 'Workbook_Open'.  Does flutter have any equivalent trigger already built in?

My web research did not return anything useful, most of the search results are to detect 1st time app launch to show a one-time-only splash screen. Not looking to detect a first time ever app launch. There are solutions that use persistency (like shared_preferences or even a database), but I am looking for a solution without using the cache nor a database.

I have some ideas, such as using global variables.

```
Pseudocode: 

x = 0; // as global variable.

if(x = 0){ run one-time-function; x++; } // on start => run function once
else if(x > 0) { do nothing } // this prevents the one-time-function for running again
```

This is a simple example to explain my question. Are there better ways to trigger a function every time the app starts?

My question sounds silly, maybe because I am used to scripting, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one time start point that before 'runApp' call in 'main' method is what you want to find?

Please refer to 'onStart' in below code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  print('onStart');
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      print('onOpen');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you. I like how simple and efficient is this solution.